# Merge all the PDF in a folder dynamically using PHP

Tags: php, pdf

I have a code that fills the pdf template based on the checkbox selection and creates the pdf in a folder. Prior to creating the pdf, it deletes all the files currently in the output folder, now I want to merged the created pdf that can be 2-5 pdf in a single pdf.

```
<?php
require('fpdm.php');    

$fields = $_POST['a'];

$t1=NULL;
$t2=NULL;
$t3=NULL;
$t4=NULL;
$t5=NULL;



if(isset($_POST['t1']))
$t1 = $_POST['t1'];
if(isset($_POST['t2']))
$t2 = $_POST['t2'];
if(isset($_POST['t3']))
$t3 = $_POST['t3'];
if(isset($_POST['t4']))
$t4 = $_POST['t4'];
if(isset($_POST['t5']))
$t5 = $_POST['t5'];

//stergere continut folder inainte de creare pdf
function recursiveRemove($dir) {
    $structure = glob(rtrim($dir, "/").'/*');
    if (is_array($structure)) {
        foreach($structure as $file) {
            if (is_dir($file)) recursiveRemove($file);
            elseif (is_file($file)) unlink($file);
        }
    }
}
//aici vine path`u catre continutul folderului ce urmeaza sters
recursiveRemove("C:\Users\Sherpu\Desktop\output");


if($t1!=NULL){ 
    $pdf1 = new FPDM('template1.pdf');
    $pdf1->Load($fields, false); 
    $pdf1->Merge();
    $pdf1->Output('C:\Users\Sherpu\Desktop\output\fpd1.pdf','F');
}

if($t2!=NULL){ 
    $pdf2 = new FPDM('template2.pdf');
    $pdf2->Load($fields, false); 
    $pdf2->Merge();
    $pdf2->Output('C:\Users\Sherpu\Desktop\output\fpd2.pdf', 'F');
}

if($t3!=NULL){ 
    $pdf3= new FPDM('template3.pdf');
    $pdf3->Load($fields, false); 
    $pdf3->Merge();
    $pdf3->Output('C:\Users\Sherpu\Desktop\output\fpd3.pdf', 'F');
}

if($t4!=NULL){ 
    $pdf4 = new FPDM('template4.pdf');
    $pdf4->Load($fields, false); 
    $pdf4->Merge();
    $pdf4->Output('C:\Users\Sherpu\Desktop\output\fpd4.pdf', 'F');
}

if($t5!=NULL){ 
    $pdf5 = new FPDM('template5.pdf');
    $pdf5->Load($fields, false); 
    $pdf5->Merge();
    $pdf5->Output('C:\Users\Sherpu\Desktop\output\fpd5.pdf', 'F');
}    
?>
```

Comment: You should make an array. Your `$_POST['tX']` can also be an array.

Answer (score 0):

It is not related to PDF merging, but it's definitely going to help you when working on your issue.

You should make an array instead of separate fields:

```
<form method="POST">

    <label for="t1">t1</label>
    <input type="text" name="t[]" id="t1" />

    <label for="t2">t2</label>
    <input type="text" name="t[]" id="t2" />

    <label for="t3">t3</label>
    <input type="text" name="t[]" id="t3" />

</form>
```

Then, in PHP, you'll be able to loop over this input:

```
foreach ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['t']); $i++)
{
    $pdf = new FPDM('template' + $i + '.pdf');
    $pdf->Load($fields, false); 
    $pdf->Merge();
    $pdf->Output('C:\Users\Sherpu\Desktop\output\fpd' + $i + '.pdf','F');
}
```

This will allow you to add an undefined amount of fields in your HTML without having to change your PHP.

Comment: I don`t have an HTML, doing this with only PHP. This is just a school project and I need to do this using only PHP.

Comment: Well, you can still use the PHP part if you send the inputs using a single field.

Comment: I don`t know how to do that... and without that the code does not work... Nevertheless thank you.